# Django 3 combine DetailView and items (ListView) from ManyToMany relationship in one template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-queryset

I'm working on a Django 3 project where I'm trying to link people to the products they use. The end goal is to display a detailed view of the person (DetailView) and include the list of products they use (ListView?). Here's what I have in my models, views, and template:

```
# models.py (omitting non-relevant fields)
class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=75, db_index=True)
    products = models.ManyToManyField('Product', through='PersonProduct')
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Product Name", max_length=75)
class PersonProduct(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

# views.py
class PersonDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Person
    queryset = Person.objects.all()
    template_name = 'person_detail.html'

# person_detail.html (simplified for clarity)
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}

<div class="person-detail">
    <h2>{{ person.first_name }} {{ person.last_name }}</h2>
</div>

<div class="gear-list">
    <ul>

<!--
This is where I'm stuck. I know I need to iterate over the products
that are associated with the person, but I can't figure out how to do it.
-->

    </ul>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

The page renders the person's detailed information just fine, but there is nothing at all there for the products he/she uses. I have confirmed that the "PersonProduct" junction table has product entries for the particular person I'm testing.

I know I have a big gap in my understanding of how this is supposed to work, but I can't find the answer anywhere. Suggestions for a solution to this problem and for other resources to read/study are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that in this way:

```
{% for product in person.products.all %}
  <li>{{ product.name }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Or, if you need the date from `through` table:

```
{% for personproduct in person.personproduct_set.all %}
  <li>{{ personproduct.products.name }} - {{ personproduct.created }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Your first suggestion worked straightaway. Thank you! Now to try extending to other models that are related to the products. I appreciate the help.